# What is this ground-cover flower which survives in the Sonoran Desert naturally?

Tags: identification, flowers, flowering, ground-cover, desert

Plants native to the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) require watering every 6 months. The following plant, which I am not sure is native to the Sonoran Desert or not, was found to thrive in the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) solely off rain. What is this flower?

This one is like a ground-cover:
[image: Shrub #4]
This closeup shows it has cross-pollinated with a similar, but yellow, flower >100' away:
[image: Shrub #4 closeup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is distinctive enough for me to offer: American Red Bush Lantana.

[image: Lantana](*Image courtesy [Monrovia](http://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/1752/american-red-bush-lantana/))*

[Lantana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana) come in many colours and it is quite normal to have two or more on the same flower head.

Comment: So it's not a cross-bread with a yellow flower? Or does this plant come in two colors?